# Sitemap in footer CSS to align/float li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have a look at the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DNB9T/

how would you float the different ul li elements so they line up beside each other them move to the next line when they hit the right boundary?

Comment: why the javascript/jquery tags?

Comment: See comments in marked answer why the javascript tags were needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to do, but you could do something like this

```
ul.sitemap > li{
    float:left;
    margin:1em;
    min-height:160px;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DNB9T/5/

Basically, `float` only direct children (first `li`s) of the `ul.sitemap`.

Add a `margin` to space them out.

Give it a `min-height` so the floated elements clear each other.  I picked `160px`, you may need to adjust.

Comment: Thanks Jason, how would you go about making them equal widths and make sure they all aligned up properly (one of the blocks near the end gets caught in the boundary of another block)

Comment: @Burt to make them all aligned, you need to give set the `width` and the `height` to the widest/tallest links.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DNB9T/10/

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is where I think jQuery and javascript could help by making the rows all the same height

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;`

```
.sitemap ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DNB9T/7/)**

Comment: That's totally different than what I thought @ShankarSangoli!

Comment: @Butt - Did you take a look at this?

Comment: @Skanker yea had a look thanks for taking the time, Jasons answer is closer to what I am looking for though

Comment: @Burt - Hmmm, you asked Jason how to give the elements equal widths, and commented that you'd use javascript to make them all the same height. So really, all you need is `display:inline-block`. Everything else seems like an waful waste of resources...